# Exec program not included in path with Java

Tags: java, apache-commons

I would like execute a program which is not included in environment path.
So, I put directory which contains my program in my variable path.
I use Java and Apache commons :

```
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
executor.setWorkingDirectory(dir);
Map<String, String> environment = EnvironmentUtils.getProcEnvironment();
environment.put("PATH", environment.get("PATH") + ":/path/of/my/program");
int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine, environment);
```

But it doesn't work : Cannot run program ... error=2, No such file or director.

When I execute a printenv before, my PATH variable is fine, and when I execute my program with absolute path it works fine.

Somebody has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I have two possible solutions:

1. You say that you are adding "/path/of/my/program" to the "PATH" variable.  But if "/path/of/my/program" is the full pathname for your program, then you should be adding "/path/of/my" to "PATH".  The "PATH" variable is a list of *directories* to be searched.
2. If you know the full pathname of the command you want to execute, you don't *need* to add it to "PATH".  You can just use it in the command line; e.g.

   ```
     String cmdLine = "/path/of/my/program arg1 arg2";
     int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine, environment);
   ```

Comment: 1. "/path/of/my/program" is directory which contains my program
2. I know full path and it works with full path like you say, but it's important for after to have my program in path

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
environment.put("PATH", "\"" + environment.get("PATH") + ":/path/of/my/program" + "\"");
```

Because path on windows is have " chracter

Comment: Shouldn't the path have a semicolon instead of a colon?

Comment: @RoiEX - Not on Linux, UNIX, Mac OSX, etcetera.  The OP is using a pathname that doesn't look like a Windows pathname.  On the other hand, I don't think that putting extra quotes around the value of PATH is correct either.